# Populate bidimensional array with single array in java

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

how do I populate a matrix in java with a array without using libs?

I have this method

```
public static String[][] transformArray(String msg, int slice) {
    String matrix[][] = new String[slice][msg.length() / slice];

    String[] msgArray= mensagem.split("");


        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
            for (int h = 0; h < matrix[j].length; h++) {
                for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length(); i++ ) {
                    matrix[j][h] = msgArray[i];
            }
        }
    }


    return matrix;
}
```

And when I call:

```
String anotherMatrix = transformArray("Java is cool", 2);
```

My return is this (i have a method to print a matrix):

```
 l l l l l l 
 l l l l l l
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want this

```
int i = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
    for (int h = 0; h < matrix[j].length; h++) {
        matrix[j][h] = msgArray[i++];
    }
}
```

You should not use 3 loops. What is happening with your code is that for each `j` and `h`, the matrix entry is being replaced with every character in turn, so every entry is ending up with the `l` from `cool`. There should not be a loop for each entry as you only want one character.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access every element within your 2D-array you would have to iterate like so:

```
for(int i=0 ; i<n ; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<n ; j++) {
        myArray[i][j] = inc;
        inc++;
    }
}
```

You instead are using three `for-loops` which is incorrect. Try adjusting your code to follow this set up, it's really easy. Edit: **pbabcdefp** has already done that for you!